# Use more upvotes!

Tags: discussion

Either there simply aren't many users on this exchange, or they're very stingy on the upvotes.

Use them! Upvote interesting questions and good answers.

This will:

- Encourage people to participate.
- Give people privileges, so they can start editing without approval, and edit tag wikis.
- Give a chance for questions to be featured on the sidebar.

Comment: I've also worried that we're to stingy with upvotes. On the other hand, I appreciate that people are (hopefully) trying to make sure to promote high quality questions and answers.

Comment: The best way to address that concern is to promote lots of upvoting _and_ downvoting, at least when the latter is merited. Votes are the single most powerful feedback mechanism on SE sites, and it's a good idea to make sure there's lots of feedback.

Answer (score 4):

I see 7 up votes here, but most of the recent questions have none-to-one up vote, and no down-vote - and the one is probably mine.

Revealed preferences much?

Answer (score 3):

Just a friendly reminder to use your voting rights more. The number of regular visitors has gone up, but average vote seems to be the same.

For example, [this question here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/6573/what-are-the-economic-benefits-of-slapp-in-file-sharing-piracy) had 0 votes after 14 hours. This probably mostly is because you don't find the subject to be very interesting. Independently, it is a very extensive and high quality question, and I believe it deserves more upvotes.

If you disagree, down vote it. Hate it or love it, but have some feelings :>